# Fatal error: Class 'conn' not found when it's there

Tags: php, class, oop

I'm new to OOP php, can someone please explain me where's the problem:

include/autoloader.inc.php:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register('autoloader');
function autoloader($class) {
  $path = "class/";
  $extension = ".class.php";
  $fullPath = $path . $class . $extension;
  if (!file_exists($fullPath))
    return false;
  include_once $fullPath;
}
?>
```

then index.php:

```
<?php
include 'include/autoloader.inc.php';
$conn = new conn();
// $user = new user();
?>
```

and class/user.class.php:

```
class conn {}
class user extends conn {}
```

I tried doing get_declared_classes():
- Before declaring $conn or $users, classes conn and users aren't listed.
- If I declare $conn I get the Fatal error from the topic. 
- If I ONLY declare $users and do get_declared_classes(), both classes are listed.

Comment: `class conn {}` is in `class/user.class.php`?

Comment: @AlexHowansky I don't know what I did but now it's working... Thanks!

Comment: _"both classes conn and user are in class/user.class.php"_ When PHP encounters `new conn()`, your autoloader fires, and looks for the class in `class/conn.class.php`, which fails. Make your code match what your autoloader is expecting by putting `conn` in `class/conn.class.php` and `user` in `class/user.class.php`.

Answer (score -1):

When you declare new user() then the both classes are listed because your autoloader file include the user class only not the conn class. This is how your autloader class is written.

Maybe you can create seperate files for your classes and load them that way!